# Compare two linear regression models in MATLAB

Tags: regression, matlab

I want to compare the performance of two models using the F statistic. Here is a reproducible example and the expected results:

```
load carbig
tbl = table(Acceleration,Cylinders,Horsepower,MPG);

% Testing separetly both models
mdl1 = fitlm(tbl,'MPG~1+Acceleration+Cylinders+Horsepower');
mdl2 = fitlm(tbl,'MPG~1+Acceleration');

% Comparing both models using the F-test and p-value
numerator = (mdl2.SSE-mdl1.SSE)/(mdl1.NumCoefficients-mdl2.NumCoefficients);
denominator = mdl1.SSE/mdl1.DFE;
F = numerator/denominator;
p = 1-fcdf(F,mdl1.NumCoefficients-mdl2.NumCoefficients,mdl1.DFE);
```

We end up with `F = 298.75` and `p = 0`, indicating mdl1 is significantly better than mdl2, as assessed by the F statistic.

Is there anyway to obtain the F and p values without performing twice fitlm and doing all the computation?

I tried to run a [coefTest](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalizedlinearmodel.coeftest.html), as suggested by @Glen_b, however the function is poorly documented and the results are not the ones I'm expecting.

```
[p,F] = coefTest(mdl1); % p = 0, F = 262.508  (this F test mdl1 vs constant mdl)
[p,F] = coefTest(mdl1,[0,0,1,1]); % p = 0, F = 57.662 (not sure what this is testing)
[p,F] = coefTest(mdl1,[1,1,0,0]); % p = 0, F = 486.810 (idem)
```

I believe I should carry the test with a different null hypothesis (C) using the function `[p,F] = coeffTest(mdl1,H,C)`. But I don't really know how to do it and there's no example.

Comment: See [here](http://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/f-statistic-and-t-statistic.html) for individual coefficients and [here](http://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.coeftest.html) for testing multiple coefficients simultaneously.

Comment: @Glen_b I'm a little confused by how coefTest works. I tried: `[p,F] = coefTest(M2,[0,0,1,1])` but it doesn't seems to give me the result I'm expecting.

Comment: I can't possibly guess what the issue is. Perhaps you need to ask a new question about that, which has a minimum reproducible example of what you did and an explanation of what you expected.

Comment: What happens when you do the coefTest?

Comment: @Glen_b I tried running `[p,F] = coefTest(mdl1,[0,0,1,1])` but it gives me completely different results. I believe I should run something with `coefTest(mdl1,H,C)`, but the `coefTest` function is poorly documented.

Comment: Yes you said that before. As I said the previous time you said it: give a minimum reproducible example of what you did and an explanation of what you expected. You didn't do it for coefTest, which is the specific thing I asked for. How can we guess what the problem is when you won't show us?

Comment: @Glen_b I've updated my post, now you can see the statistic and reproduce the example ('carbig' is an example dataset from matlab). Just copy and run the code.

Comment: You do not want `coefTest(mdl1,[0,0,1,1])` as that is testing the restriction that `b.Cylinders + b.Horsepower = 0`. You want to test the restrictions that `b.Cylinders = 0` and `b.Horsepower = 0`. See my answer for full explanation on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is in regards to comparing two linear regression models where one model is a restricted version of the other.

#### Short answer:

To do an F-test on the restriction that the 3rd and 4th elements of your estimated, coefficient vector `b` are zero:

```
[p, F] = coefTest(mdl1, [0, 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 0, 1]);
```

#### Further explanation:

Let `b` be our estimated vector. Linear restrictions on `b` are typically written in a matrix form: `R*b = r`. The restriction that 3rd and 4th element of `b` are zero would be written:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0    *    b    = [0
 0, 0, 0, 1]                0];
```

The matrix `[0, 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 0, 1]` is what coefTest calls the `H` matrix in the docs.

```
P = coefTest(M,H), with H a numeric matrix having one column for each
    coefficient, performs an F test that H*B=0, where B represents the
    coefficient vector.
```

#### Long version

Sometimes with this econometric routines, it's nice just to write it out yourself so you know what's really going on.

Remove rows with NaN because they just add unrelated complexity:

```
tbl_dirty = table(Acceleration,Cylinders,Horsepower,MPG);
tbl = tbl_dirty(~any(ismissing(tbl_dirty),2),:);
```

Do the estimation etc...

```
n = height(tbl);  % number of observations
y = tbl.MPG;
X = [ones(n, 1), tbl.Acceleration, tbl.Cylinders, tbl.Horsepower];
k = size(X,2);     % number of variables (including constant)

b = X \ y;                 % estimate b with least squares
u = y - X * b;             % calculates residuals 
s2 = u' * u / (n - k);     % estimate variance of error term (assuming homoskedasticity, independent observations)
BCOV = inv(X'*X) * s2;     % get covariance matrix of b assuming homoskedasticity of error term etc...
bse = diag(BCOV).^.5;      % standard errors

R = [0, 0, 1, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 1];

r = [0; 0];          % Testing restriction: R * b = r 

num_restrictions = size(R, 1);
F = (R*b - r)'*inv(R * BCOV * R')*(R*b - r) / num_restrictions;   % F-stat (see Hiyashi for reference)

Fp = 1 - fcdf(F, num_restrictions, n - k);  % F p-val
```

For reference, can look at p. 65 of Hiyashi's book Econometrics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I'm not obtaining exactly the same results, using my computation I obtain F = 298.7467 while using your technique we get F = 288.4303. The data I used has no missing values. Am I doing something wrong with my computation?

Comment: @mat Check your mdl1 and your mdl2 variables used to calculate the F by the (SSR_-SSR_u) etc... method and you'll find that mdl1 is fit with 392 observations while mdl2 uses 398. There are several observations where the MPG variable is NaN, leading fitlm to use fewer observations on mdl1. If you use the same set of observations, all three methods return the same result. I uploaded code here: http://pastebin.com/hM9CUFWw

Comment: It's working, this is gonna be very useful for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

Fitlm fits an arbitrary model. In your case a regression model with an intercept and either one or three regressors. It might seem that the model with three regressors can use information from the model with one regressor, but this is only true if there are some restrictions on the model and even then this overlapping information is limited. 
Fitlm is a very general framework which can be used for arbitrary models. Doing multiple regressions at the same time with sharing of information can thus get quite complex and is not implemented. 
It is possible to implement this yourself for these two specific models. Usually such a linear regression is solved using the covariance matrix:

```
 Beta = (X' X) ^-1 X' y
```

were X is the data with the variables as columns and y is the target variable. In this case you could reuse part of the covariance matrix for which you only need the columns from the smaller regression: the variation in Acceleration. Since adding 2 new variables adds 8 values yo the covariance matrix you only save 1/9 of the time. Furthermore, the heaviest part is the inversion. Thus the time improvement is very very little.

In short, just do two separate regressions

Comment: I don't really want to compare the performance of each model separately, I would like a single comparison.

Comment: It's preferable to solve a linear system instead of multiplying by an inverted matrix. i.e. `Beta = (X'*X) \ (X'*y)` is more efficient & accurate than `inv(X'*X) * (X'*y)`. In fact, with the way the \ operator works, you can actually just do `Beta = X \ y` to solve the system in the least squares sense.